# OneToMany связь Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Имеется связь OneToMany, У одного Region есть много Districts. 
Имеется простой REST контроллер, который возвращает все Region, но ответ приходит

```
    {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Test",
    "districts": null
}
```

Districts - null. Это неприятно.

```
    @GetMapping("/regions")
public ResponseEntity<List> getAllRegions() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(regionService.getAllRegions(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Юзаю JPA репозитории для доступа к данным в бд.

Часть Region

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "regions", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<District> districts;
```

Часть District

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "region_id")
private Region region;
```

В Бд у таблицы districts добавился столбец region_id в котором ID региона, к которому относится. 
Собственно сам вопрос, как мне вытягивать для GET маппинга Регионы, чтобы дистрикты тоже подгружались. 
Ну и забегая наперед, как мне добавлять POST маппингом дистрикты лучше? Пробовал

```
{
"name": "Distr",
"regionId": 1
}
```

Предварительно код подшаманив, в бд пишет все, вопросов нет. Указал явно ID Региона и название дистрикта, верно ли так?

P.S Понял, что проблема в FetchType, а точнее оно не подгружает все как надо. Если поменять на EAGER, идет

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Kiyv","districts":[{"id":7,"name":"qqqq","regions":{"id":1,"name":"Kiyv","districts":[{"id":7,"name":"qqqq","regions":{"id":1,"name":"Kiyv","districts
```

до stackoverflow, если сделать set дистриктов transient, то null.

Comment: Как минимум вот тут `mappedBy = "regions"` должно указываться имя поля в соответствующем классе, у вас же указано `regions`, а поле называется `region`. Исправьте сперва это, а потом могут ещё пляски с бубном и с `LAZY` начаться

Comment: спасибо за ответ, это я косячнул при копипасте с ide. Все соответствует, как надо)

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что я должен дистрикт репозиторием добавлять дистрикты в регионы вручную в регион сервисе ибо выдает null от того, что оно не знает, что они есть? Либо же сама связь говорит о том что оно должно знать?

Comment: FetchType.EAGER надо, либо чтобы сразу вернул данные, либо поработать над DAO

Comment: По порядку) у меня изначально в Set districts установлен как transient. Если я убираю его, то при тестировании в постмане идет странное зацикливание и все не читабельно. Если поиграться с EAGER в двух местах или в одном, то ничего из этого не выходит. Мне выдает stackovetflow, плюс отображает всего 1 значение из базы с зацикливанием `[{"id":1,"name":"Kiyv","districts":[{"id":7,"name":"qqqq","regions":{"id":1,"name":"Kiyv","districts":[{"id":7,"name":"qqqq","regions":{"id":1,"name":"Kiyv","districts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, советовали не в то направление.
Всем, кто советовал EAGER - зачем, если мне нужно Lazy?
Решил аннотацией @JsonIgnore над сетом дистриктов и все заработало

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, у вас ленивая подгрузка связей установлена нужен EAGER и маппинг в District у вас "region".

Измените на :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "region", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<District> districts;
```

и все должно заработать, если остальное все настроено верно.

Или, если вы хотите Lazy, то можно подтянуть данные:

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Region r JOIN FETCH r.districts WHERE r.id = (:id)")
Region findById(@Param("id") int id);
```

в вашем сервисе. И тода подтянутся остальные регионы.